# How can I receive the notification when the iOS device is connnected or disconnnected to my mac?

Tags: ios, macos

I am a macOS developer, and I am trying to implement this feature:

When the iPhone or iPad is connected or disconnected to the Mac, my App needs to receive a notification, and then display or remove it on `NSView` .

I have made the following attempts:

1. `Disk Arbitration Framework` - `DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback` &
   `DARegisterDiskDisappearedCallback`.
2. `NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification` &
   `NSWorkspaceDidUnmountNotification`.
3. `ExternalAccessory Framework` - `EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification` & `EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification`

Unfortunately, all three methods have failed. Methods 1 and 2 can only know the connection event of the USB flash drive, and method 3 can only be used for MFI accessories.

Could anyone tell me how to implement this feature?

---

I learned from the comment section of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020655/how-to-get-device-id-vendor-id-and-product-id-of-a-mounted-usb-device-in-mac-os) that maybe I should try to use `IOKit` to solve this problem. But after I read Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000011), I was lost.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I searched many times, I found the answer to the question.

`libimobiledevice`provides a monitoring [function](http:///**%20Callback%20to%20notifiy%20if%20a%20device%20was%20added%20or%20removed.%20*/), If you subscribe to this function, you can receive notifications.